# How to customize Django confirmation form and view in password request

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement resetting password in Django 1.6 with my own templates instead of the custom Django administration auth_view and I've mainly followed this tutorial;https://ruddra.com/posts/implementation-of-forgot-reset-password-feature-in-django/. I've managed to customize the reset password page and the email sent for resetting the password but the confirmation page, which the resetting link is sent to is blank when I try to use the PasswordResetConfirm() class without Django administration forms (which work). In short, when clicking the email link for resetting password the webpage is blank but titled Confirmation at the top, so something in the code is blocking or missing. I've tried numerous of tutorials but nothing works. I've changed /rest/.. to account/reset in the URL's, which matches the link in the email and now works for getting to the  PasswordResetConfirmView(), but it renders the error 'SetPasswordForm' object has no attribute 'set_cookie', how can I fix this in Django 1.6?. I've also noticed that I can't import update_session_auth_hash, which many tutorial use, in Django 1.6 and it seems to exist in Django 1.7 and later versions. Instead I'm trying to use the password hashers PBKDF2PasswordHasher, SHA1PasswordHasher in this tutorial; https://apimirror.com/django~1.9/topics/auth/passwords but I'm not sure if it's related to the Attribute error about set_cookies in the SetPasswordForm.

I've tried by placing 'django.contrib.admin' in INSTALLED_APPS in Settings after the applications, which 'unplugs' the custom Django administration form for changing password in the confirmation step to a blank page with the text Confirmation on top. I've also changed the template password_reset_confirm.html

````
In views.py, following from linked tutorial

class PasswordResetConfirmView(FormView):
 template_name = "registration/password_reset_confirm.html"
 success_url = 'registration/password_reset_complete.html'
 form_class = SetPasswordForm


 def post(self, request, uidb64=None, token=None, *arg, **kwargs):
    """
    View that checks the hash in a password reset link and presents a
    form for entering a new password.
    """
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None  # checked by URLconf
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError,UserModel.DoesNotExist):
          user = None

    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, 
    token):
        if form.is_valid():
            new_password= form.cleaned_data['new_password2']
            user.set_password(new_password)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Password has been reset.')
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:

          messages.error(request, 'Password reset has not been   
          unsuccessful.')
          return self.form_invalid(form)
    else:
        messages.error(request,'The reset password link is no longevalid.')
        return self.form_invalid(form)```


In urls.py


url(r'^account/password_reset/', ResetPasswordRequestView.as_view(), 
name="reset_password"),
url(r'^account/password/reset/done/', ResetPasswordRequestView.as_view(), 
name="reset_password_done"),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 
PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),name='password_reset_confirm'),

# changed url to
url(r'^account/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 
PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),name='password_reset_confirm'),
# which matches email link
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/account/reset/{{ uid }}/{{ token }}/ 

In password_reset_confirm.html in the Registration folder

{% extends 'base.html' %}



{% block title %}Enter new password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Set a new password!</h1>
<form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" value="Change my password">
</form>
{% endblock %}

# in forms.py from tutorial, works in the tutorial example but yields 
 # an Attribute error that the form doesn't have set_cookies  
 # after disconnecting from Djando Admin confirmation forms used in the 
 #tutorial
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):

# """
#
#A form that lets a user change set their password without entering the old
# password
# """
error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': ("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
new_password1 = forms.CharField(label=("New password"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)
new_password2 = forms.CharField(label=("New password confirmation"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def clean_new_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
    if password1 and password2:
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
                )
    return password2
````

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve the problem in my question. If anyone runs into the same problem, I did the following;

The tutorial example worked but the admin view showed up even after removing all of the Django administration (admin) related tags in the template password_reset_confirm.py (even after running manage.py syncdb and tossing and starting a new sql-db), so I used a new template called test_reset_confirm.html in the Registration folder with the form related code part (middle section) from the original password_reset_confirm.py, and I filled in the form information by adding enctype = multipart/form-data;

and info in the password field

                                                                
In views.py I changed the PasswordResetConfirmView from a class to a function, following Example 9 in this tutorial; https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/54414/django.contrib.auth.forms.SetPasswordForm;

```
 def PasswordResetConfirmView(request, uidb64=None, token=None,
                       token_generator=default_token_generator,
                       post_reset_redirect=None,current_app=None):
    """
   View that checks the hash in a password reset link and presents a
   form for entering a new password.
"""
UserModel = get_user_model()
form = SetPasswordForm(request.POST)
template_name='registration/test_reset_confirm.html'
assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None  # checked by URLconf

try:
    uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, UserModel.DoesNotExist):
    user = None

if user is not None and token_generator.check_token(user, token):
    validlink = True
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SetPasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print request.POST,'request.POST'
            print form.cleaned_data,'form.cleaned_data'

            new_password= form.cleaned_data['new_password2']

            user.set_password(new_password)
            user.save()
            #form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your password has now been    changed and you can login on any system site!',fail_silently=True)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)


else:
    form = SetPasswordForm()

c = {"form":form}
c.update(csrf(request))

return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, c,
                        current_app=current_app)

# Setpasswordform in forms.py

class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
 new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
 new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

 error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': ("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }


 class Meta:
     model = User
     fields = ('password',)
 def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SetPasswordForm, self).clean()

        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: after resetting the password using this code. when I click on password reset link in the email it is opening password cofirmation page. There is any way I can show message saying invalid link once after reset.?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by the original poster does not apply any password validators, which means that the user can set the password to something very unsafe.

Below is updated code which will apply the password validation properly:

views.py:

```
def set_password_confirm_request(request, uidb64=None, token=None,
                       token_generator=default_token_generator,
                       post_reset_redirect=None,current_app=None):

    if request.method == "POST":

        try:
            uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
            user = User.objects.filter(pk=uid).first()
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None

        if user is not None and token_generator.check_token(user, token):
            set_password_form = SetPasswordForm(request.POST)
            if set_password_form.is_valid():
                new_password = set_password_form.cleaned_data['new_password2']
                user.set_password(new_password)
                user.save()
                return render(request=request, template_name="accounts/login.html",
                              context={"message": "Your password has been updated.", "message_color": "green"})

            if set_password_form.data["new_password1"] != set_password_form.data["new_password2"]:
                errors = ["Passwords do not match."]
            else:
                errors = set_password_form.errors["new_password2"]
            return render(request=request, template_name="accounts/password_reset_confirm.html",
                          context={"message": errors, "message_color": "red"})

    set_password_form = PasswordResetForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="accounts/password_reset_confirm.html", context={"password_reset_confirm_form": set_password_form})
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password

class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):

    new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, validators=[validate_password])
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, validators=[validate_password])

    error_messages = {
       'password_mismatch': ("The two password fields didn't match."),
       }

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('password',)

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
       super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```